# Google Cloud Build of Angularfire project times out

Tags: angular, angularfire, google-cloud-build

When trying to build a prod build of an angular + firebase project, it always times out. I see that it is nearly finished, but the step for building the prod version of the angular application is already taking up > 8 min.
When building it locally it takes only 50s.

[cloud build steps image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elp8Y.png)

These are the steps I use in the cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
##########
# FUNCTIONS
##########
# Install
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
  args: ['install']
  dir: 'functions'

##########
# HOSTING
##########
# Install
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
  args: ['install']
  dir: 'hosting'
# Build
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
  args: ['run', 'build', '--', '--prod=$_IS_PRODUCTION']
  dir: 'hosting'
  env:
    - some environment variables here containing api keys etc...

##########
# DEPLOY
##########
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: ['deploy', '-P', '$_BUILD_LINE']
```

The non-production build is working fine and taking up only 4 mins in total (for all steps).

Any ideas why the cloud build of the angular prod build takes so long and how I can reduce it?

Comment: Hey luhu, I cannot tell just from the code why the build has timed out. Can you please provide the build details that you can find in your Cloud Build page to see where the problem lies?

Comment: Hi Nahuel, there's no real error message, the prod build just takes for ages (> 8min) and then the 10min timeout stops the build: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/33Gw9pL) 
Are there any other details that could help investigating on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries with different solutions I found one that is working: Thanks to [Methkal Khalawi's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58306205/3920200) regarding "every step copy the assets that produced from the previous step" I modified the build to install all dependencies and then run the build in one step:

Add script in package.json:

```
"build-from-scratch": "npm install && npm run build"
```

Then execute this script in the cloudbuild.yaml:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
  args: ['run', 'build-from-scratch', '--', '--prod=$_IS_PRODUCTION']
  timeout: 600s
  dir: 'hosting'
```

Since the npm modules do not have to be copied from the install to the build step now, the build just takes ~3min now.

Answer (score 0):

@lunu I investigated on this and replicated your issue here this is my analysis:

- The default timeout for a step is 10 minutes
- As the build process is divided into steps, every step copy the assets that produced from the previous step.
- I suspect step#2 which timed out  because it was copying a lot of files and I guess their size is huge.

What I suggest is to add [“timeout” option](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build.FIELDS.timeout) to the build step in this manner:

```
# Build
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
  args: ['run', 'build', '--', '--prod=$_IS_PRODUCTION']
  timeout: 900s
  dir: 'hosting'
  env:
    - some environment variables here containing api keys etc…
```

I put it here 900 seconds which is 15 minutes you can change it to meet your needs.

Anyway there are some [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds) to consider if the build is taking so much time:

- Building leaner containers
- Using Kaniko cache
- Using a cached Docker image
- Caching directories with Google Cloud Storage
- Using custom virtual machine sizes
- Avoiding the upload of unnecessary files

Comment: Thanks for your tips! Unfortunately most of it did not help, e.g. the timeout is limited to 600s now.
Building cached docker containers etc would have definitely helped but would not be worth the effort for such a small project that just takes 50s on my local machine.
But I now found a solution and posted it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58491711/3920200